# Get client machine name from IP

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to get the client machine name from the IP adress.

If I am getting the IP address of client from -

`ip_addr = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`nbtstat –a #{request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']}`
```

Ruby backticks run the resulting string at the command prompt.

But that probably gets you the name of their subnet router, not the literal machine. Then again, I know next to nothing about internet routing protocols, etc.